# Pandas group by selected dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, normalize

I have a dataframe that is very similar to this dataframe:

| index | date | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-12-1 | 12 |
| 1 | 2020-03-1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2020-07-1 | 7 |
| 3 | 2021-02-1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2021-09-1 | 9 |

And i want to combine all dates that are closest to a set of months. The months need to be normalized like this:

| Months | Normalized month |
| --- | --- |
| 3, 4, 5 | 4 |
| 6, 7, 8, 9 | 8 |
| 1, 2, 10, 11, 12 | 12 |

So the output will be:

| index | date | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-12-1 | 12 |
| 1 | 2020-04-1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2020-08-1 | 8 |
| 3 | 2020-12-1 | 12 |
| 4 | 2021-08-1 | 8 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the DataFrame and use **replace** to change the dates.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': ["2019-12-1", "2020-03-1", "2020-07-1", "2021-02-1", "2021-09-1"], 
                        'month': [12,3,7,2,9]})
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row['month'] in [3,4,5]):
        df['month'][index] = 4
        df["date"][index]  = df["date"][0].replace(df["date"][0][5:7],"04")
    elif (row['month'] in [6,7,8,9]):
        df['month'][index] = 8
        df["date"][index]  = df["date"][0].replace(df["date"][0][5:7],"08")
    else:
        df['month'][index] = 12
        df["date"][index]  = df["date"][0].replace(df["date"][0][5:7],"12")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try creating a dictionary of months where:

`norm_month_dict = {3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 8, 7: 8, 8: 8, 9: 8, 1: 12, 2: 12, 10: 12, 11: 12, 12: 12}`

then use this dictionary to map month values to their respective normalized month values.

`df['normalized_months'] = df.months.map(norm_month_dict)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct a dictionary from the second dataframe (assuming `df1` and `df2`):

```
d = (
 df2.assign(Months=df2['Months'].str.split(', '))
    .explode('Months').astype(int)
    .set_index('Months')['Normalized month'].to_dict()
)
# {3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 8, 7: 8, 8: 8, 9: 8, 1: 12, 2: 12, 10: 12, 11: 12, 12: 12}
```

Then `map` the values:

```
df1['month'] = df1['month'].map(d)
```

output:

```
   index        date   month
0       0  2019-12-1      12
1       1  2020-03-1       4
2       2  2020-07-1       8
3       3  2021-02-1      12
4       4  2021-09-1       8`
```